# Change a value of an .ini files in multiple directories

Tags: powershell

I need to change a value in the DefaultPrint.ini file in multiple users "home" directory.

I've managed to make a powershell script to change the value on a single user, but I am struggeling making the script accept multiple users.

```
$User = "Max"

$IniPath = "\\Network1\Home\$User\"

foreach ($User in $User)
    {   
        $IniFile = "$IniPath\DefaultPrint.ini"
     
        $IniText = Get-Content -Path $IniFile

        $NewText = $IniText.Replace("Old_Priter","New_Printer")

        Set-Content -Path $IniFile -Value $NewText -Force
    }
```

The directories I need to enter to find the files is based on the usernames, so I need to change the file in:
\Network1\Home\Max
\Network1\Home\John
\Network1\Home\Sophia
etc

The script above is working for a single user, and I am trying to adapt it to work with multiple users though a .csv file

I tried the following

```
$User = "Max","John","Sophia"
```

But it does not seperate the user directories but gathers them togther? (\Network1\Home\Max John Sophia)

I also tried to import via csv, as I need to do this on 200+ users

```
$User = (Import-Csv -Path .\Users.csv).User
```

But it ends up doing the same, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move this statement:

```
$IniPath = "\\Network1\Home\$User\"
```

inside the loop, so that the path is updated with the correct `$user` every time, and then rename the `$User` variable used outside the loop (`$Users` seems an appropriate name here):

```
$Users = -split "Max John Sophia"

foreach ($User in $Users)
{   
    $IniPath = "\\Network1\Home\$User\"

    $IniFile = "$IniPath\DefaultPrint.ini"
 
    $IniText = Get-Content -Path $IniFile

    $NewText = $IniText.Replace("Old_Priter","New_Printer")

    Set-Content -Path $IniFile -Value $NewText -Force
}
```

Comment: You need to remove the last backslash from `"\\Network1\Home\$User\"` or use `Join-Path` to construct variable `$IniFile`, otherwise there will be a double backslash in the path..

Comment: @Theo `Get-Content -Path` won't trip over ```\\```